# Taking input and using it for calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take the input of discount from user in the form xxxx.xx or xx% and change the calculation method for the amount.

```
//amount = mrp - discount (if discount is xxxx.xx)
    //amount = mrp - discount * mrp (if discount is xx%)

function doMath() {
  var mrp = parseInt(document.getElementById('inmrp').value);
  var discount = (document.getElementById('indiscount').value).String();
  var dis = discount[2];
  var di = discount[1];
  if (dis = '%' || di = "%") {
    discount = (parseInt(discount))/100;
    amount = mrp - mrp * discount;  
  } else {
    discount = parseInt(discount);
    amount = mrp - discount;
  }
  document.getElementById('outamount').value= amount ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var di = discount.substr(discount.length - 1);  
  if (di == "%") {
   ..........
   .....
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8e8D3/)

Comment: Thanks Nouphal.M

Had to Make some changes but thanks you your tip I finally got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Objects dont have a `String` function, but your might be looking for `toString()`. However it's unecessary since the `value` property of an input of type text is already a *string*.

```
var discount = document.getElementById('indiscount').value;
```

Also, it might be safer to check if the last character is a `%` sign rather than always checking the third one.

```
var isPercent = discount[discount.length - 1] === '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the function indexOf to know if there is a '%' in the text. And then if it is there do a substring to remove it.

```
function doMath() {
  var mrp = parseInt(document.getElementById('inmrp').value);
  var discount = document.getElementById('indiscount').value;
  if (discount.indexOf('%') != -1) {
    discount = discount.substring(0,discount.length)
    discount = (parseInt(discount))/100;
    amount = mrp - mrp * discount;  
  } else {
    discount = parseInt(discount);
    amount = mrp - discount;
  }
  document.getElementById('outamount').value= amount ;
}
```